# Why does MySQL ignore null values when looking for not equal?

Tags: mysql, null

I am noticing something weird in MySQL and I would like to see why it behaves this way and of there a way to change it?

**Scenario**

I have accounts InnoDB table with the following columns `id, name, type` where the type is a null-able.

Now, lets say I have 10 records where the type = "TEST" and 100 records with they `type IS NULL` and 20 records where the type = "STANDARD"

If I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE type <> "TEST"
```

This query will only show me the the 20 records that have type = "STANDARD" only and it ignores the 100 records that have a null value.

To work around this I would have to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE IFNULL(type,"") <> "TEST"
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (type <> "TEST" OR type IS NULL)
```

NULL value means blank "aka no value" and no value means <> "TEST"

It is probably an expected behavior but I am not sure why is it designed like so

Comment: This is the SQL standard.  That is the way that operations on `NULL` are defined in the language.  And, `NULL` does not mean "no value"; it means "unknown".

Comment: What about `<=>` - is that MySQL specific, and is there an opposite  other than wrapping in `NOT()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE type <> "TEST"
```

The meaning of this statement would be,

"Select the rows from `accounts` where the value of column `type` is not equal to 'TEST' ".

Which means MySQL returns the records having a value in `type` which is not equal to "TEST".

Now here, since `NULL` means there is no value, it does not return those records which does not have any value for `type` column.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` means "the value cannot be known/is not known": which is different to "no value" - a comparison cannot be carried out at all against an unavailable value.